# Implementing GridSearchCV with scorer for Leave One Out Cross-Validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I am attempting to implement scikit-learn's GridSearchCV for Gaussian Process Regression (GPR). I'm using a small dataset of ~200 points, and would like to use LOOCV as a performance evaluator for my model. My setup is:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import *
from sklearn.ensemble import *
from sklearn.gaussian_process import *

param_grid = {
    'kernel':[kernels.RBF(),kernels.Matern(length_scale=0.1)],
    'n_restarts_optimizer':[5,10,20,25],
    'random_state':[30]
}
res_GPR = GridSearchCV(estimator=GaussianProcessRegressor(),param_grid=param_grid,cv=LeaveOneOut(),verbose=20,n_jobs=-1)
res_GPR.fit(X,y)
```

where X and y are my data points and target values respectively.
I know that the scoring method returned by GPR is r^2, which is undefinable for the LOOCV case (since there is only one test element) - this is verified by obtaining NaN for the .best_score_ attribute of the fitted model.
As such, I would like the model to be scored with just the Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) for each test case, averaged over all the iterations. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` includes a `scoring` argument, which you may use to set your score to negative RMSE:

```
res_GPR = GridSearchCV(estimator=GaussianProcessRegressor(),
                       param_grid=param_grid,
                       cv=LeaveOneOut(),
                       verbose=20,
                       n_jobs=-1, 
                       scoring = 'neg_root_mean_squared_error')
```

See the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) and the [list of available scores](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter) for more.